# Load already live HTML file from server instead of browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server, browser-cache

I have a live website, but as changes are always there, I need the user to view the latest HTML files, i.e. load the files from the server instead of browser cache.

When this website went live I didn't know about:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I have made my website using HTML, CSS, jQuery and PHP where necessary.

What can I do to make the website load directly from the server?

Comment: Can't you just update the html with those `meta` tags? If not, what can you update?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis I updated the HTML code with the meta tags, but since I already have the page in my cache, the new HTML code (with meta tags) is not running. I can simply hard refresh and work, but the users won't know or do that.

Comment: If you also have acess to your server's configuration, cache-control headers can also be of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: @LaurentS. This is new for me, I'll look into it thanks.

Comment: @LaurentS. Is there any other way, other than your previous suggestion?

Comment: Meta tags and cache-control headers are the best solutions. Changing the name of the pages would also do the trick. Other than that I don't think there's any way to force client refresh of a page.

Comment: @LaurentS. Okay, it seems I'll have to dig about cache-control headers, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I updated the HTML code with the meta tags, but since I already have the page in my cache, the new HTML code (with meta tags) is not running. I can simply hard refresh and work, but the users won't know or do that.

If you need to force everyone's browser to reload a plain `.html` page you could add the ['Cache-Control` header](https://www.keycdn.com/support/cache-control) to your webservers configuration:

**Nginx**

```
location ~* \.(html)$ {
 add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
}
```

**Apache**

```
<filesMatch ".(html)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store"
</filesMatch>
```

If the change however is in a file that your `.html` page is loading, such as a `.js .css` you can use this 'cache busting' technique:

```
script.css?v=1.0 // This is the URL for release 1.0
script.css?v=1.1 // This is the URL for release 1.1
script.css?v=1.2 // etc.
```

This will force the browser to load the new file.

Comment: Hey, I knew about this technique, but the changes aren't in the script or css files.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include ways to send the `Cache-Control` header that should make the browsers request the clean version if you have access to your webservers configuration.

Comment: I am using cPanel server, will have to dig deep, thanks!

Comment: Make a `.htaccess` file in your servers webroot directory that has this: `Cache-Control: "no-cache, no-store"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv=“Pragma” content=”no-cache”><meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″><meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
```

**Try this . But When you force a site to load from the server instead of the cache, you affect performance. Therefore, before you add these meta tags to your site, ask yourself if this is truly necessary and worth the performance hit that the site will take as a result.**

Comment: Hi Lakshmi, as mentioned in my question, I already know about the meta tags, the issue was for the users who have already opened the site (code without the meta tags), their code wouldn't be updated and hence the meta tags won't work.